# How to fill the blank in "Many of the world's great novels are reported ___ (make) into movies last year."?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, tenses, sentence, past-tense

I'm an English learner and came across an exercise question today:

**Sentence**: Many of the world's great novels are reported ___ (make) into movies last year.

**Choices**: [made/to be made/to have been made/have been made]

Which is grammatically correct and which sounds more natural? If more than one answer is correct, is there any difference about the meaning of them?

PS: this sentence seems to be weird for me, my intuition tells me

*"Many of the world's great novels WERE reported to have been made into movies last year."*

is more natural. Is my intuition right?

Comment: Your sentence means the *reports* were made in the past. The original means the reports are still current.

Comment: Had you thought of joining our [ell.se] site? It might be of interest and use to you.